# Legitimacy of drawing a complex curve like a plane curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intuition

In algebraic geometry, we often consider a complex algebraic curve, and in order to get some intuition, we often draw it on the plane as if it were a plane curve. In most cases it turns out that the plane drawing really helps us thinking of the curve for instance when counting the number of intersections. Then I wonder, **to what extent the plane drawing is legitimate (or not misleading) to "represent" the complex algebraic curve?**

Comment: Eisenbud has some exercises exhibiting the potential pitalls early on in his book on commutative algebra. I'll try to look this up later. My feeling is that it's generally the other way around: we pick (especially early on) examples that lend themselves to drawing.

Comment: I like your phrasing "really helps"

Comment: This is an appealing question, but so open-ended it seems difficult to answer definitively. (Examples: Real points of hyperelliptic curves comprise disjoint unions of ovals, while the complex curves are connected; the real points can be smooth when the complex curve is singular, etc., etc.) For calibration about drawing simplified pictures: My advisor would typically draw a rectangle (the total space) with a line segment underneath (the base space) while saying "Let $P$ be a principal bundle over $M$...." This never felt truly misleading. :)

Comment: Note that any drawn curve has finite arc-length and is even piecewise differentiable. But say the Jordan curve theorem works with infinite arc-length too. And in complex analysis the Cauchy-Goursat theorem doesn't require a piece-wise differentiable curve; merely rectifiable (finite arc-length) is enough. I know this is about algebraic curves so my comment is only slightly related.

Comment: I always have the example of a hyperbola $xy=1$ when I think about when drawing a curve in $\mathbb{C}^2$ fails. As a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the hyperbola has two pieces (seemingly it is not irreducible). But it actually is irreducible, the two pieces connect in what we do not draw...